# JavaScript Substr Google Tagmanager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to figure out how to strip the last 4 characters using a Google Tagmanager  Macro function.

the CookieLanguage var is defined in another Google Tag that reads a string from a cookie. This sting contains data similar to: 'kjhooij;lpuououpo-9999' and I need to capture the last 4 characters.

```
function() {
  try {
    var cookie = {{CookieLanguage}}.substr(CookieLanguage.length - 4);
    return cookie[0];
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("No cookie found");
    return "n/a";
  }
}
```

Somehow my cookie var remains empty, am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe because your second `CookieLanguage` occurrence should be `{{CookieLanguage}}` too?

Comment: "substr" does not return an array, does it? So why are you returning "cookie[0]" instead of just "cookie" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function() {
  try {
    var cookieLanguage = {{CookieLanguage}},
     cookie = cookieLanguage.substr(cookieLanguage.length - 4);
    return cookie[0];
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("No cookie found");
    return "n/a";
  }
}
```